# Java Program Notification

Tags: java, terminal, notifications, console

I have a java program, that has a console that shows in Terminal (im using mac os) and I want to be able to show basic notifications, like the ones that pop up in the corner or something. It could also involve the icon bouncing or something. What's the easiest way to do that? Is there an easy way to do that without using external libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly using JOption pane. Import looks like:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

and lets say you have a method called

```
public void gotNotification(){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You just received a notification!!!");
}
```

that way a box pops up saying "You just received a notification!!!". Thats the best suggestion I have.